# how to get text from a span of a input field when it gains focus?

Tags: jquery, text, input, this, html

How can i get the text from a span that precedes an text input and when that input gains focus get the span of the focused input? lets say that the inputs are like this:

```
<div>
<label for="id">...</label>
<input type="text" id="id" value="" />
<span class="span">span</span>
</div>
```

is there a way to get the value maybe something like this:

```
$('#id').live('focus', function(){
var text = $(this, '.span').text();
});
```

I do a live binding because the inputs are dynamically created
i've also tried something like this but does not seem to work:

```
var text = $(this).find('.span').text();
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean a span that **succeeds** your input?  That's how your html is structured.

I think this is what you're looking for

```
$('#id').live('focus', function(){
   var text = $(this).siblings("span:first").text();
});
```

Or if you're 100% certain that the span will always be right next to the input, you could do

```
$('#id').live('focus', function(){
   var text = $(this).next().text();
});
```

But if you really do want the span that comes immediately before your input, you could use the `prev` function:

```
$('#id').live('focus', function(){
   var text = $(this).prev("span").text();
});
```

---

Finally, note that `live` is deprecated.  Normally I'd recommend switching to `on`, but since you're just selecting a single element by id, why not simply do:

```
$('#id').focus(function() {
   var text = $(this).prev("span").text();
});
```

Or to make this more general, and able to work with *any* input

```
$(document).on("focus", "input[type='text']", function() {
   var text = $(this).prev("span").text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the span is the next element:

```
$('#id').live('focus', function(){
   var text = $(this).next().text();
});
```

Also no need to give the class `span` to your span.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#id').live('click', function(){
   var text = $(this).siblings('span').text();
   alert(text);
});
```

**[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/hHyFa/2/)** // here is use `click`, you can change this to `focus`

[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)